# GAS Nesting Scriplets in Templated Pages

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Trying to figure out why this doesn't work. The rest of the page loads just fine but where the menu items would be expected it just says "HtmlOutput" - no buttons, no links, nothing but text. Nothing in the mBar div displays - just text ("HtmlOutput"). I've also tried printing and force printing the scriplet in the menuBar.html file with no luck.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
    var html = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    return html;
}

function include(file, appData) {

    var component = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
    component.data = appData;
    return component.evaluate();

}
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="mainContent" class="w3-hide">

    <!-- Menu Bar -->
    <?= include('menuBar', oUser)?>

</div>
```

**menuBar.html**

```
<div class="mBar">
    <a href="#" class="mBarItem">Select Period</a>
    <? if (data.isAdmin == true) { ?>
    <a href="#" class="mBarItem">Manage Periods</a>
    <a href="#" class="mBarItem">Manage Users</a>
    <? } ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**include** function should return type *string*, so change it this way:

```
function include(file, appData) {
    var component = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
    component.data = appData;
    return component.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

***edit:***

Also you need to use [force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets) to avoid escaping of your included html code (note "**!**" symbol):

```
<?!= include('menuBar', oUser)?>
```

Comment: Ahhh...you are clever. That totally worked.

Also, I had to modify the data object as well. It should have been data[0].isAdmin because I passed in an array Object.

THANKS!!